# could not connect to APNS(Apple Push Notifications Server) using Rails, apn_sender gem

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using **Rails 3.2.2** and **apn_sender 1.0.5 gem**. I have generated proper **apn_development.pem** and **apn_production.pem**. I have added them in my rails application. By looking at some article, i have modified the apn_production.pem files permissions also. still i am not able to connect to Apple's APNS Server from my Rails Application.

```
feedback_data = APN::Feedback.new(:environment => :production), still returns
#<APN::Feedback: Connection not currently established to feedback.push.apple.com on 2196>
```

Am i missing something or does any body have a detailed tutorial of how to send (APNS) Apple push notifications from a Rails Application.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this gem: [kw_apn](https://github.com/kupferwerk/kw_apn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. After generating proper certificates, i was having issue with "development build of the application for other environments". By replacing the mobile application with appropriate build, problem was solved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the APN::Feedback.new() returns # which is a bit misleading. I thought there was a connection elsewhere that I had to make.

Turns out, I just had to call the .data method to start the connection

```
feedback_data = APN::Feedback.new().data
```